# Progress bar as milestones

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I have written code for a progress bar to increase dynamically when I clicked on a specific milestone.

When I click on a milestone I want the color to stay red but I can't add `onclick` method to every div.

I have updated code ,i have inserted columns in a row so that i want keep progress bar in first column, but the dots are over flowing. can any one help?

```js
var mileStones = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.primary-color'));
mileStones.forEach(elem => {
  elem.onclick = function() {
    const current = this;
    let flag = false;
    document.getElementById('pp').style.width = current.dataset.width + '%';
    mileStones.forEach(elem => {
      elem.classList.add('active');

      if (flag) elem.classList.remove('active');
      if (current.id === elem.id) flag = true;

    });
  }
});
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #00A2DB;
}

#one,
#two,
#three,
#four,
#five {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#one,
.percent {
  left: 0%;
}

#two,
.percent1 {
  left: 25%;
}

#three,
.percent2 {
  left: 50%;
}

#four,
.percent3 {
  left: 75%;
}

#five,
.percent4 {
  left: 100%;
}

.primary-color {
  background-color: pink;
}

.primary-color:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-9">
    <p>Business case completion:</p>
    <div class="progress" id="progress">
      <div class="primary-color" id="one" data-width="0"></div>
      <div class="primary-color" id="two" data-width="25"></div>
      <div class="primary-color" id="three" data-width="50"></div>
      <div class="primary-color" id="four" data-width="75"></div>
      <div class="primary-color" id="five" data-width="100"></div>
      <div class="progress-bar" id="pp" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" onclick="progressBarTest()"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 align-self-end">
    <p class="primary1"> ID 453</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "the color should stay red" you mean, the dot that is pink should become red?

Comment: yes @CalvinNunes

Comment: I have updated code ,i have inserted columns in a row so that i want keep progress bar in first column, but the dots are over flowing. can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic method to set onclick for every miles stone, and you can use a class "active" to maintain the active style, you can also benefit from data attributes in order to make the function dynamic..

**Edition**
To persist the milestones that are before the clicked one you can use a flag. in order to achieve this.

```js
var mileStones = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.primary-color'));
mileStones.forEach(elem => {
  elem.onclick = function() {
    const current = this;
    let flag = false;
    document.getElementById('pp').style.width = current.dataset.width+'%';
    mileStones.forEach(elem =>{ 
      elem.classList.add('active');
      
      if(flag) elem.classList.remove('active'); 
      if(current.id === elem.id) flag = true;
           
    }); 
  }
});
```

```css
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #00A2DB;
}

#one,
#two,
#three,
#four,
#five {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#one {
  left: 0%;
}

#two {
  left: 25%;
}

#three {
  left: 50%;
}

#four {
  left: 75%;
}

#five {
  left: 100%;
}

.primary-color {
  background-color: pink;
}

.primary-color:active, .active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="primary-color" id="one" data-width="0"></div>
  <div class="two primary-color" id="two" data-width="25"></div>
  <div class="three primary-color" id="three" data-width="50"></div>
  <div class="four primary-color" id="four" data-width="75"></div>
  <div class="five primary-color" id="five" data-width="100"></div>
  <div class="progress-bar" id="pp" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" onclick="progressBarTest()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great.. But i when i click on second milestone the first two dots should stay red. if third milestone the three dots should stay red @RenzoCalla  Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 2):

Just [delegate](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983) the click event by listening for it in the progress bar itself (`#progress__base` in the example below).

You can then check [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) to know which element was clicked and its index and use that to calculate the new progress percentage and add or remove an `.active` class to all the milestones that come before or after the clicked one.

Actually, if you use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) in your CSS, you can simplify your code a lot and make it work with any number of milestones without changing any CSS or JavaScript code, just adding more or less of them in the HTML:

```js
const progressBase = document.getElementById('progress__base');
const progressBar = document.getElementById('progress__bar');
const progressPoints = Array.from(progressBase.children).slice(1);

progressBase.onclick = function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  
  if (!target.classList.contains('progress__bullet')) {
    // Ignore clicks on #progress__base and #progress__bar
    return;
  }
  
  const index = progressPoints.indexOf(target);
  
  progressBar.style.width = `${ 100 * index / (progressPoints.length - 1) }%`;
  
  // Add the active class to all the ones that come before the
  // clicked one, and the clicked one itself:
  for (let i = 0; i <= index; ++i) {
    progressPoints[i].classList.add('active');
  }
  
  // Remove the active class from all the ones that come after
  // the clicked one:
  for (let i = index + 1; i < progressPoints.length; ++i) {
    progressPoints[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
};
```

```css
#progress__base {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#progress__bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transition: width ease-in 250ms;
}

.progress__bullet {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: pink;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress__bullet:active,
.progress__bullet.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress__base">
  <div id="progress__bar"></div>
  
  <div class="progress__bullet active"></div>
  <div class="progress__bullet"></div>
  <div class="progress__bullet"></div>
  <div class="progress__bullet"></div>
  <div class="progress__bullet"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain or provide any link by using **Flexbox** @Danziger

Comment: @KeerthiReddyYeruva You have both the implementation with Flexbox and a link to MDN in the answer. You can also take a look here to get familiar with it: http://flexboxfroggy.com/